# Can I use gBrowser.selectedBrowser.addProgressLisnter in e10s?

Tags: firefox-addon

We're trying to migrate our add-on to message manager and frame scripts. 
Previously our add-on used gBrowser.addProgressListener() and nsIWebProgressListener.onStateChange() along with browser.webProgress.isLoadingDocument to monitor network activity.

The question is can I continue using browser.addProgressListener and browser.webProgres.isLoadingDocument in future versions of Firefox or using webProgress from frame script is a better way to do that?  Maybe I should use some other technique?

For some reason it doesn't work reliably in Firefox 36.0a1 so I thought I should maybe move the code to frame script. Namely frame's docShell is QI-ed to webProgress to add progress listener there. It also doesn't work in all cases so I guess it's just a bug in 36.0a1.

By "doesn't work reliably" I mean that onStateChange() isn't called when I try navigating by browser.loadURI() method when a blank page is loaded in the current tab. Also webProgress from frame script sometimes "forgets" to send STATE_STOP to onStateChange().

Comment: I think it will add via automatic cpow but im not exactly sure: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox/Cross_Process_Object_Wrappers